# 「七つの海商社」"7 Seas Trading Co." as formal name for a company

Tags: kanji, kana

wanted to ask a question re:company names in 日本語.

Would「七つの海商社」work as a name for a company? Or does this combo of kana+kanji not work in formal business names?

Greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [wiki page](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A4%BE%E5%90%8D) gives same law regulations about how to name a company. To give a simple summarize: a company is free to name its company. However, the name of an entity which is not a company cannot make its name look like a company; the name a company must include one of "株式会社", "合名会社", "合資会社", "合同会社" to the kind of the company. Currently, Kanji, Kana, Roman letter, number, "&", " " (space), "・", etc. can be used in company name.

So, for 七つの海商社, if it is a company, I think it is lacks the part showing its kind("株式会社", "合名会社", "合資会社", "合同会社").

As to 七つの海 part, I think it is ok to name a company, thought it may be hard to guess what the company does.

As a matter of fact, there is a company called [「株式会社七つの海」](http://www.sevenseas-co.jp/).